# How to omit query name returned from sql to CSV

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, csv

I'm doing CSV exports from database table with postgres. 
The script I call via linux is constructed by 4 main sql queries, but what I wan't to save in CSV is only 3rd step. Below I present how import process is executed:

1. execute via linux bash script:
   `$sudo -u postgres -H sh -c "psql -d openstreetmap -f extractTagsFromEditorToCsv.sql" > $CSV_OUTPUT_FILE`
2. construction of extractTagsFromEditorToCsv.sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_tags 
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ah_edited boolean default TRUE;

INSERT INTO temp_tags
SELECT DISTINCT ON (way_id, k)
way_id, k, v, version, ah_edited
FROM way_tags
ORDER BY way_id, k, version desc;

COPY 
      (SELECT temp_tags.way_id, temp_tags.k, temp_tags.v, temp_tags.version, TRUE
      FROM temp_tags
      JOIN ways ON temp_tags.way_id = ways.way_id AND temp_tags.version = ways.version
      JOIN changesets on ways.changeset_id=changesets.id
      JOIN users ON changesets.user_id=users.id
      WHERE (k like '%maxspeed:backward%'
             OR k like '%maxspeed:forward%'
             OR k like '%maxspeed%')
      AND ((users.email like '%ah.com%' AND ways.changeset_id != 0)
            OR temp_tags.ah_edited = TRUE))  TO STDOUT (format csv, delimiter ';', header false);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tags;
```

In result I receive file which for example looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
INSERT 0 13426
8135845;maxspeed;501;10;t
DROP TABLE
```

That file isn't correct parsed by CSV read tool. 
My question is: Is it possible to omit sql method name printed in the output? Perhaps I could  divide that script in 3 separate and export CSV from 'the middle' with only extracting files, but maybe there is some way to do it in one sql script file.

 Expected output result would be like:
`8135845;maxspeed;501;10;t`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `-q` (quiet) switch. `"psql -q -d openstreetmap -f extractTagsFromEditorToCsv.sql"`

Comment: That's what I wanted to achieve. Thank you very much!